# Kivy - Label Text Not (Always) Dynamically Updating

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having an issue with updating dynamically my label text.

I'm making a physical recording device using a Raspberry pi and my goal is to keep track of the state of my recorder (Recording/Not Recording) by updating a label.

The program work as such: **Check if the button is pushed** --> **Record**--> **Check if the button is pushed** --> **Stop Recording**

I manage to update successfully the label **only** when  **no** other functions are called after **self.ids.lab.text** statement:

**Updating successfully**

```
if self.Buttpress() == 0:
            self.ids.lab.text = "Pressed"
```

**Not updating successfully**

```
if self.Buttpress() == 0:
            self.ids.lab.text = "Pressed"
            self.assign_action()
```

Here is a breakdown code:

```
#test_kivy.py 

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Setting pin board pin mode
global pin
pin = 10 #Button pin
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Sets raspi internal resistors to pull-up


class Test(Screen):

    # Counter Keeping track of recording state
    rec = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Scheduling the start of the program, giving time to the GUI to initialise
        Clock.schedule_once(self.mathere isin, 4)


    # Assigning the state of my button        
    def Buttpress(self):
        buttpress = GPIO.input(pin)
        return buttpress

    # Checking if button is pressed (1 = not pressed, 0 = pressed)   
    def button_state(self):
        while self.Buttpress() == 1:
            self.Buttpress()

        if self.Buttpress() == 0:

            # updating label when pressed
            self.ids.lab.text = "Pressed"
            self.assign_action()

    def assign_action(self):
        if self.rec == 0:
            print("Recording")
            # updating label to Recording...
            self.ids.lab.text = "Recording..."
            self.rec = self.rec+1

            #Debounce time
            time.sleep(1)
            self.button_state()

        if self.rec == 1:
            print("Not rec")
            # updating label to Recording...
            self.ids.lab.text = "Recording Stop"
            #Updating recording state
            self.rec = self.rec-1

            #Debounce time
            time.sleep(1)
            self.button_state()

    def main(self,dt):
        self.button_state()



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):code
    pass


class TestGui(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('test_kivy.kv')
        return Test()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestGui().run()
```

And my .kv file:

```
#text_kivy.kv

<CustLabel@Label>:
    font_size: 26
    color: (0.3,0.5,0.9,1)
    size_hint: (0.2, 0.1)
    background_color: (0.3,0.5,0.6,1)

<Test>:
    size: root.width, root.height
    id: main_menu

    FloatLayout:     
        CustLabel:
            id : lab
            text: "Not Pressed"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.39,"top":1}
```

I have spent 3 days trying to have a successful label update, using **ID's**,  **ObjectProperty**, **App.get_running_app()** and else.

I am relatively new Kivy so I hope there is not too much garbage above.

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't updating the label text, but rather it's with the rest of your code that blocks the gui so it can't update. When you write `time.sleep` that's exactly what happens, the program doesn't do anything including updating what is drawn to the screen.

The options are:

1) Use `Clock.schedule_once` to schedule a function that ends the recording, instead of `time.sleep`. This is a straightforward option in this case.

2) Do your recording stuff in a thread